# how to redirect http:// to https:// nuxtjs website hosted on heroku?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, heroku, nuxt.js

My website is build upon nuxtjs and php, We added ssl certificate and domain became https, but when user login to http:// website goddady shows them that this domain is parked free, courtesy of GoDaddy.com.
I wrote that I should add htaccess file and here is what I did

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Heroku way
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And I put this file to main directory of the source code,
but even though it doesn't work, Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Heroku is handling HTTPS for you AFAIK. Are you sure you need to add something else by yourself here?

Comment: When I go to http:// website, it doesn't redirect to https:// website, I wanna fix that

Comment: "http:// website goddady shows them that this domain is parked free" - Are the HTTP and HTTPS sites pointing to different services?

Comment: Did you properly checked on Heroku's side?

Comment: @MrWhite I think so, that's why it shows different content?

Comment: @Kissu Actually, I couldn't find useful information on heroku's side, I don't know what exactly to check there ?1 , could you please help me with that ?

Comment: Did you checked this one? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl If you have a paid dyno, this should be a click and go solution in your settings somewhere.